# Does this implementation of mutex locks result in undefined behavior?

Tags: c, thread-safety, locking, pthreads

I need to control the frequency at which `main` processes data. In the example, it just increases the value of a variable. I cannot use `sleep` inside of `main` because I need the frequency to be constant (and I don't know exactly how long does it take to process all the data). I just know for a fact that whatever processing I need to do takes less than 2 seconds, so I just need to prevent `main` from increasing `x` more than once every two seconds.

The solution I've found involves using two mutexes: locking one in `main` and unlocking it in an `extra` thread, and locking the other in `extra` and unlocking it in `main`. This `extra` thread sleeps for 2 seconds per cycle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void  *extra(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_t *lock = (pthread_mutex_t *) arg;
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock[0]);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock[1]);
        sleep(2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    pthread_mutex_t lock[2];
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock[0], NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock[1], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock[1]);

    pthread_t extra_thread;
    pthread_create(&extra_thread, NULL, &extra, lock);

    while(1) {
        x += 1;
        printf("%d\n", x);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock[0]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock[1]);
    }
}
```

## The Problem

The reason why this works is that `main` cannot lock `lock[0]` twice; it has to wait until `extra` unlocks it. However, according to [The Open Group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)

> Attempting to relock the mutex causes deadlock. If a thread attempts
>   to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked,
>   undefined behavior results.

## The Question

Based on this, I see two issues here:

1. If `main` tries to lock `lock[0]` twice it should deadlock.
2. `extra` unlocking `lock[0]`, which was locked by `main`, should be undefined behavior.

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: Re, "I cannot use `sleep()`...because I need the frequency to be constant." Sure you can use `sleep()` (or, more likely, [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html)). The trick is, don't just _blindly_ sleep. [Look at the clock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html), compute how much time until the next time your thread is due to wake up, and then sleep for that amount of time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, wouldn't this be a problem if I need to change the way `main` processes data? Each time I change the data processing I would need to recompute how long this takes.

Comment: Not "each time [you] change the data processing," but _every time around the main loop_. At the bottom of the main loop, you look at what time it is now, you look at what time you need to perform the next iteration, you take the difference, and then you sleep for that many nanos.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, I see, I misunderstood. That seems like a good solution; thank you.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: If you use `clock_nanosleep()` with the `TIMER_ABSTIME` flag, you don't even have to calculate the time difference - just directly sleep until the time you need to perform the next iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your questions,

> 1. If `main` tries to lock `lock[0]` twice it should deadlock.

Yes, it would.  Unless you use recursive mutexes, but then your child thread would never be able to lock the mutex as `main` would always have it locked.

> 2. `extra` unlocking `lock[0]`, which was locked by main, should be undefined behavior.

Per the [POSIX documentation for `pthread_mutex_unlock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_unlock.html), this is undefined behavior for a `NORMAL` **and** non-robust mutex.  However, the `DEFAULT` mutex does not have to be `NORMAL` and non-robust so there is this caveat:

> If the mutex type is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT`, the behavior of `pthread_mutex_lock()` [and `pthread_mutex_unlock()`] may correspond to one of the three other standard mutex types as described in the table above. If it does not correspond to one of those three, the behavior is undefined for the cases marked.

(Note my addition of `pthread_mutex_unlock()`.  The table of mutex behavior clearly shows that unlock behavior for a non-owner varies between different types of mutexes and even uses the same "dagger" mark in the "Unlock When Not Owner" column as used in the "Relock" column, and the "dagger" mark refers to the footnote I quoted.)

A robust `NORMAL`, `ERRORCHECK`, or `RECURSIVE` mutex will return an error if a non-owning thread attempts to unlock it, and the mutex remains locked.

A simpler solution is to use a pair of semaphores (the following code is deliberately missing error checking along with empty lines that would otherwise increase readability in order to eliminate/reduce any vertical scroll bar):

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
sem_t main_sem;
sem_t child_sem;
void *child( void *arg )
{
    for ( ;; )
    {
        sem_wait( &child_sem );
        sleep( 2 );
        sem_post( &main_sem );
    }
    return( NULL );
}
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    pthread_t child_tid;
    sem_init( &main_sem, 0, 0 );
    sem_init( &child_sem, 0, 0 );
    pthread_create( &child_tid, NULL, child, NULL );
    int x = 0;
    for ( ;; )
    {
        // tell the child thread to go
        sem_post( &child_sem );
        // wait for the child thread to finish one iteration
        sem_wait( &main_sem );
        x++;
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    pthread_join( child_tid, NULL );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sane thread-safe solution is a condition variable:

```
//main thread
while(1) {
    x += 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

then in the sleeper thread you do:

```
//sleeper thread
while(1) {
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    sleep(2);
}
```

However you can also read the current time from the operating system and the sleep for the remaining time until next epoch using the high resolution sleep and time.

The next option is using a timerfd to wake you up in a fixed interval. And it can let you know if you missed a wake up.

Comment: How about using the critical section?
Will there be the same outcome?

Comment: *The sane thread-safe solution is a condition variable*  I disagree.  Proper use of a condition variable requires a predicate condition shared across threads along with the condition variable and mutex themselves.  `pthread_cond_wait()` is also subject to spurious wakeups without any call to `pthread_cond_signal()` or `pthread_cond_broadcast()` nor any error indication, so code to robustly and properly use condition variables has to be much more complex.  A single semaphore can often replace all of that.